# Conditionally hiding columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide columns (Z,AA,AB,AC) if one of dependent cells are blank. i.e. if Range1 is blank entire column Z is hidden, Range2 is blank then entire column AA is hidden etc.

I know I could implement simple If Else/ .EntireColumn.Hidden statment but I was thinking to use code like below to make it neater. Any suggestions how to make it work ?

```
Sub(test)
Dim cell As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As Range


 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ReturnedHoldMail")

   Set MyArray(1) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range1")
   Set MyArray(2) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range2")
   Set MyArray(3) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range3")
   Set MyArray(4) = Sheets("test1").Range("range4")


    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
         On Error Resume Next
            For Each cell In MyArray(i)

             If Len(cell.Value) < 1 Then

               cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
               Else
               cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

            End If

        Next

    Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Range1,Range2`... are cells from each column?

Comment: `sub test()` ...change it

Comment: With this code, you keep looping through every cell in  range1 turning column visible then invisible depending on contents of cell. So it ends up being either hidden or visible based on the last cell checked. So if range1 was A1:A4 it's only A4 that determines the state. I don't think that's what you intended.

Comment: Range1-4 are conditional ranges responsible for disappearance of adequate columns. Range1 (if empty) hides column Z, range2 (if empty)hides column AA etc. but they placed different position then hidden columns, hope this make sense

Comment: @Harassed Dad you're right i am not but was hoping to go this direction (array) so far I implemented this 
 If Range("Range1").Value <> "" Then
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If  and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ranges that are hidden to be independent of the ranges being tested for emptiness, try the following:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As Range
    Dim HideArray(1 To 4) As Range
    Dim will_hide As Boolean

    Set MyArray(1) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range1")
    Set MyArray(2) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range2")
    Set MyArray(3) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range3")
    Set MyArray(4) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range4")

    Set HideArray(1) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range5") ' or eg. Sheets("test2").Range("Z:Z")
    Set HideArray(2) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range6")
    Set HideArray(3) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range7")
    Set HideArray(4) = Sheets("test1").Range("Range8")


    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        will_hide = True
        For Each cell In MyArray(i)
            If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
               will_hide = False
            End If
        Next
        HideArray(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = will_hide
    Next

End Sub
```